# Modx Revo как отследить что пользователь посетил страницу и выполнить действие?

Tags: javascript, php, cookie, modx, revo

Встал вопрос об отслеживании поведения пользователя, а именно:

На странице основного родителя через pdoMenu вывожу все дочерние элементы текущего ресурса.

```
    --Отец 1
    --- svg галочка серого цвета Сын 1
    --- svg галочка серого цвета Сын 2
    --- svg галочка серого цвета Сын 3
    --Отец 2
    --- svg галочка серого цвета Сын 1
    --- svg галочка серого цвета Сын 2
    --- svg галочка серого цвета Сын 3
...
```

Очень интересно разобраться как сделать так, чтобы если юзер (например) зашел на страницу какого-то "сына", то на странице основного родителя цвет галочки изменять на зеленый и чтобы она оставалась зеленой даже если пользователь перезагрузит страницу/разлогинется и залогинится.

Comment: Если не критично пропадание данной информации, то проще сохранить в cookie или localStorage. Если нужно навсегда, то пишите информацию в базу данных, при загрузке дочернего объекта

Comment: @ArchDemon Извиняюсь если моя просьба покажется Вам глупой, но не могли бы Вы дать мне ссылку на доки или пример как это делается? а то я вообще профан в этом. Спасибо